# Why my secondary namenode always start at the same machine with namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using Apache Hadoop 3.3.6.

I have setup in hdfs-site.xml that:

```
  <property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.https-address</name>
    <value>192.168.56.193:9869</value> 
  </property>
```

But when start up, my secondary namenode start at the same IP with namenode (192.168.56.213). How can I fix it?

I have try to search Internet but cannot receive any statisfied answers.

Comment: This configuration only sets how to connect, not where to run the process

Comment: Can you show me which file and property to set the process run?

Comment: start-dfs should run it, but you want a **standby** namenode for a highly available cluster, not a secondary https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.6/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH to that server and explicitly start the Secondary Namenode

```
$ ssh 192.168.56.193
$ $HADOOP_HOME/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh start secondarynamenode
```

You can verify that the Secondary Namenode is running by checking the Hadoop logs or running the following command:

```
$ $HADOOP_HOME/bin/hdfs dfsadmin -report
```